# How to replicate the behavior of the left toolbar of Qt creator?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to add a Left Tool bar to my GUI project.

With the following code I was able to add the toolbar.

```
leftMenu = createLeftMenu();
addToolBar(Qt::LeftToolBarArea, leftMenu);
```

```
QToolBar* MainWindow::createLeftMenu() {
    auto *toolBar = new QToolBar("Left Menu");
    toolBar->setObjectName("Left Menu");

    toolBar->setMovable(false);
    toolBar->setFloatable(false);

    auto *widget = new QWidget;

    auto editBtn = new QToolButton;
    setLeftButton(editBtn , "editBtn");
    editBtn ->setToolTip("Edit");
    addBuildMenuOptions(editBtn);

    auto setupBtn = new QToolButton;
    setLeftButton(setupBtn, "setupBtn");
    setupBtn->setToolTip("Setup");
    addSetupMenuOptions(setupBtn);


    auto vLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    vLayout->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
    vLayout->setSpacing(0);

    vLayout->addWidget(editBtn);
    vLayout->addWidget(setupBtn);

    widget->setLayout(vLayout);
    toolBar->addWidget(widget);

    return toolBar;
}
```

I would like to have a similar behavior to the Qt Creator left bar.

[image]

In the Qt Creator toolbar, each option on the left bar has different content on the right side of the window, so all the content changes when we click on any icon, similar to having different tabs.

I would like to implement something like this, for example, a section to edit the default properties using `tags`, `dropdowns`, `checkboxes`, `comboboxes`, etc. And another section to show the results of a process with tables/graphs, etc.

I don't know what I should create when the left bar icons are clicked. Should I create a new `QWidget` that contains a `QVBoxLayout`? If I do, it means that all objects will be removed when clicking any option in the left bar and the settings and results of each section will be lost.

what could be the correct way to do this?

Comment: The Qt Creator left sidebar is not really a "toolbar". It is more like switching tabs. So I suggest QStackedWidget, and then the icons on the left just switch the widget in that.